# Siri says "speak you like to"; is there something messed up with my phone?

Tags: siri

Whenever I ask Siri to call a business, she will go through each result and say "Speak you like to call it, get directions...". Is there something wrong with my phone? "Speak you like to" is definitely not idiomatic english (at least not in the US), so it's hard to believe something like this would slip by Apple QA. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

I've found exactly how to reproduce it. I'm using Best Buy as an example, but I would imagine any business will do.

1. Connect a bluetooth device (I use my car, but a headset may work)
2. With the phone locked, activate Siri and say "Call Best Buy"

She'll say something like "I've found two places named Best Buy fairly close to you. The first is X miles away. Speak you like to...".

Comment: What's the exact question you ask Siri to get that response?

Comment: This is intriguing. What about a series of screenshots?

Comment: .. and an audio file?

Comment: Try changing your phone's language from English (Dagobah) to English (US)

Comment: See my edit for how to reproduce. Looks like it only happens over Bluetooth.

Comment: Love James Hebden's solution. LOL

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing wrong with your phone.

Yes, Apple messed up.

Ever wonder why you have to have an Internet connection to use Siri? All the voice-to-text transcribing is done on Apple's servers - *and* those servers tell your phone exactly what to display *and* what to say.

So, you should probably tell Apple about it - post something on their support forums, file a Radar, something. Most likely, it can be fixed server-side.